# Prove or disprove the following proposition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove or disprove the following proposition: There are no positive integers $x$ and $y$
such that $$x^2 - 3xy + 2y^2 = 10$$

Comment: What is the double primes?

Comment: I edited it to read correctly. Should be $$x^2 -3xy + 2y^2 = 10$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$x^2 - 3xy +2y^2 = (x-2y)(x-y) =10$$

Comment: I think you need negatives in between.

Comment: Fixed already, thanks.

Comment: You got it. Nice solution.

Comment: @user113273, now see what the two quantities $(x-2y), (x-y)$ can be.